# jQuery Validate: Validate One Field at a Time

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I know jQuery Validate shows only one error at a time by default. My intention is to create a form that enables the submit button only if the form is filled out correctly. Here are my two snippets:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('input').on('blur', function() {
        if (jQuery("#validate-info").valid()) {
            jQuery('#toggle-delivery').removeClass("btn-disabled");  
        } else {
            jQuery('#toggle-delivery').addClass("btn-disabled");
        }
});
  jQuery("#validate-info").validate({         
    rules: {
     phone_number: {
        required: true,
        digits: true,
        minlength: 9
     },
     email_address: {
        required: true,
        email: true
      },
      shipping_first_name: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 2
      },
      shipping_last_name: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 2
      }
    },
    onfocusout: function(e) {
            this.element(e);
    },
    onkeyup: false,
    messages: {
         phone_number: {
          required: "Please enter a valid UK phone number",
          digits: "Please enter a valid UK phone number.",
          minlength: "Please enter at least 9 characters"
         },
         email_address: {
            required: "We need your email address to contact you.",
            email: "Oops! This isn't a correct email format. Please check and try again."
         },
         shipping_first_name: {
          minlength: "Please enter at least 2 characters."
         },
         shipping_last_name: {
          minlength: "Please enter at least 2 characters."
         }
    }
  });
    });
```

The button has the "btn-disabled" class by default. If the form is valid, the class is removed and the button is clickable/submits the form.

I also have this snippet to retain input values if the user leaves the page without submitting the form:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(window).unload(saveSettings);
    loadSettings();
});

function loadSettings() {
    jQuery('#shipping_first_name.input-text').val(localStorage.shippingfirstname);
    jQuery('#shipping_last_name.input-text').val(localStorage.shippinglastname);
    jQuery('#email_address.input-text').val(localStorage.emailaddress);
    jQuery("#phone_number.input-text").val(localStorage.phonenumber);
    jQuery("#shipping_address_1.input-text").val(localStorage.shippingaddress);
    jQuery('#billing_first_name.input-text').val(localStorage.billingfirstname);
    jQuery('#billing_last_name.input-text').val(localStorage.billinglastname);
    jQuery('#billing_email.input-text').val(localStorage.billingemailaddress);
   jQuery("#billing_phone.input-text").val(localStorage.billingphonenumber);
    jQuery("#billing_address_1.input-text").val(localStorage.billingaddress);
    jQuery('input#ship-to-different-address-checkbox[value="' + localStorage.billtoaddress + '"]').prop('checked', true);
}

function saveSettings() {
    localStorage.shippingfirstname = jQuery('#shipping_first_name.input-text').val();
    localStorage.shippinglastname = jQuery('#shipping_last_name.input-text').val();
    localStorage.emailaddress = jQuery('#email_address.input-text').val();
    localStorage.phonenumber = jQuery("#phone_number.input-text").val();
    localStorage.shippingaddress = jQuery("#shipping_address_1.input-text").val();
    localStorage.billingfirstname = jQuery('#billing_first_name.input-text').val();
    localStorage.billinglastname = jQuery('#billing_last_name.input-text').val();
    localStorage.billingemailaddress = jQuery('#billing_email.input-text').val();
    localStorage.billingphonenumber = jQuery("#billing_phone.input-text").val();
    localStorage.billingaddress = jQuery("#billing_address_1.input-text").val();
    localStorage.billtoaddress = jQuery('input#ship-to-different-address-checkbox[type=checkbox]:checked').val();
}
```

This autofills the form when the user comes back to the page (either by accidentally refreshing it, or by navigating to another page).

My problem is that now, if a user navigates to the page to fill out the form (for the first time), and completes the first field, when selecting the next one, the validation is triggered and all the other fields show up red with the error message under each input field. See a screenshot:

[image]

How can I prevent this? I want to validate each field and show errors individually, not all at a time. I suspect it has something to do with the `on('blur'` part of the snippet. I tried `change` and `keyup` instead of `blur`, but the result is the same. Of course, I'm not an expert, so I'm not sure if that really is the actual problem.

Any tips? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that it's most likely being caused by your `blur` event handler. Try changing this:

```
if (jQuery("#validate-info").valid()) {
```

To this:

```
if (jQuery("#validate-info").validate().checkForm()) {
```

The `checkForm()` function should return a boolean based on whether the form is valid or not, but it won't cause any validation error messages to appear.

Comment: Brilliant! It's working perfectly now, thanks a bunch!